# Symfony Canonical link without page numbers

Tags: php, symfony, canonical-link

I am doing some amends to PHP site that uses Symfony. I want to add canonical tag on the news listing page. I have managed to get the link in the head section but I cannot get the correct URL.

The URL should be: `http://www.example.com/news` but it is append the page number when I go onto the next page `http://www.example.com/news/1`

I have tried

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),
    app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) }}
```

and a variety of other combinations

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How is the route defined?

Comment: I think that you try to send data into application in GET request. 
You need to create POST so you can send data to your controller in other way than route parameter. Fastest way will be sending POST through form. Other way to handle this - use AJAX.